# Overlapping Grid Elements: 2nd div fails to load

Tags: css, css-grid

Both divs display correctly alone, but if both img-1 and img-2 divs are both in the container, the second div disappears.

HTML:

```
<div class="body-background">
    <div class="background-img-1"></div>
    <div class="background-img-2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.body-background {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.background-img-1 {
    background: red;
    grid-column: 1 / 3; 
}
.background-img-2 {
    background: blue;
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

Shouldn't the boxes overlap normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give both background divs a `grid-row: 1` property (which becomes `grid-row: 1 / 2`). I don't think the browser likes having to give it implicitly to two overlapping cells.

```css
.body-background {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
.background-img-1 {
    background-color: red;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.background-img-2 {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-background">
    <div class="background-img-1"></div>
    <div class="background-img-2"></div>
</div>
```